# Multiple parameters corrections algorithm to correct flow rate readings

Tags: parameters, mathematical-optimization, minimize, error-correction

I have temporal readings of multiple flow meters of different zones.

```
A[a1, a2, a3...an], 
F[f2, f2, f3......fn]
n is the zone number, A is air flow, F is fuel flow
```

THEORETICALLY, one can calculate a theory `O2` from `A/F`. That is `g(A/F)=O2T`. 
There is a measured `O2`, namely `O2M`.

Since the flow meter of air and fuel is not correct, there's a gap between `O2T` and `O2M`.

I tried introduce a correction factor `k[k1, k2,....kn]` to have the `k` multiply `A` to correct the flow. Using `scipy.optimize.fmin` to calculate `k` to minimize `(O2T-O2M)`. But it failed.

I wonder if anyone can provide me some idea or code on calculating k to minimize `O2T-O2M`. With the `k` calculated, the zonal flow rate can be corrected by using data.

Thanks.

Comment: highlighted points in text

Comment: Assuming you don't have weird outliers - If `k` is constant, then optimum `k` is simply the average of `(O2T - O2M)`. if `k` can vary then simply `k[i] = O2T[i]/O2M[i]`.

Comment: @Shree Thank you for your reply.  I think you might misunderstand my question. I want to correct each air and fuel flow to match the O2M. There's only one O2M, there will be only one O2T. However, the O2T was manipulated by k1, k2, ....kn. Therefore, k[i]=O2T[i]/O2M might not give me the expected k[i].